# Find the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ where $0<x<\pi/2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ where $0<x<\pi/2$.

I believe that $\inf=0$ and $\sup=1$. However I am having difficulties formally showing so. I was thing if I take the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as $x\to \infty$ will show that $\sup=1$, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim that the supremum is one follows from the facts that $|\sin x| \le x$ for all $x$ together with $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

The infimum is not correct, however, Notice that $\sin x / x$ is a decreasing function on $(0, \pi/2)$ (as is easily verified from, say, its derivative), and so its minimum on $[0, \pi/2]$ is attained at the right hand endpoint. This won't be zero.

Comment: So for the case of the $\inf$ I would do $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{sin(x)}{x}=\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Yes, that gives the correct infimum.

Comment: So formally how would I say that these are the answers? Would it begin by saying that $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is a decreasing function on the interval. Hence .... the limits?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Honestly, a lot of the proof depends on what you know about the sine function. Assuming that you can prove or assert that the function is decreasing, then you can just notice that there are upper / lower bounds of $1$ and $2/\pi$ and then show no higher/lower bound works due to continuity of the function.